# bottom overflowed by 42 px ,tried all my best cannot understand why this happens

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Even though I wrapped everything in a single child scroll view why it's overflowing on rotation can anyone help. I'm not sure but it could be due to sized boxes placed in between the children of the column. Also, I didn't want the single child scroll view to scroll. This is among my first few projects in the flutter

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  bool _isHiddenPassword = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final topPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      },
      **child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,**
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [
                  primary_gradient_color,
                  secondary_gradient_color,
                ])),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: topPadding,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Fashion Ai",
                  style: logo_text_style(),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 12,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                  child: TextField(
                      controller: null,
                      style: simple_text_style(),
                      decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("Email")),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: _isHiddenPassword,
                    controller: null,
                    style: simple_text_style(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _isHiddenPassword = !_isHiddenPassword;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              _isHiddenPassword
                                  ? Icons.visibility_off
                                  : Icons.visibility,
                              semanticLabel: _isHiddenPassword
                                  ? 'show password'
                                  : 'hide password',
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 16,
                            )),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                        hintText: "Password",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 8),
                    child: Text(
                      "Forgot Password?",
                      style: medium_text_style(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              colors: [
                                primary_button_gradient_color,
                                secondary_button_gradient_color
                              ])),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Sign in",
                            style: button_text_style(),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              colors: [
                                primary_button_gradient_color,
                                secondary_button_gradient_color
                              ])),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            "Assets/google.svg",
                            height: 20,
                            width: 20,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 15,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Sign in with Google",
                            style: button_text_style(),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8,),
                Container(
                  height: 15,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Don't have account? ",
                        style: simple_text_style(),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => SignUp()),
                                  (route) => false);
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Register now",
                          style: medium_text_style(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use single child scroll view on the column rather than on Container. There can be many solutions but doing Container > SingleChildScrollView > Column should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping the `SingleChildScrollView` around `Container` wrap it around `Column`

Add `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to the `physics` field in `SingleChildScrollView` for never allowing to scroll

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  bool _isHiddenPassword = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final topPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [
                primary_gradient_color,
                secondary_gradient_color,
              ])),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(


            // ***** For not scrolling *****
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),


            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: topPadding,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Fashion Ai",
                  style: logo_text_style(),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 12,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                  child: TextField(
                      controller: null,
                      style: simple_text_style(),
                      decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("Email")),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: _isHiddenPassword,
                    controller: null,
                    style: simple_text_style(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _isHiddenPassword = !_isHiddenPassword;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              _isHiddenPassword
                                  ? Icons.visibility_off
                                  : Icons.visibility,
                              semanticLabel: _isHiddenPassword
                                  ? 'show password'
                                  : 'hide password',
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 16,
                            )),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                        hintText: "Password",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4,
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 8),
                    child: Text(
                      "Forgot Password?",
                      style: medium_text_style(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              colors: [
                                primary_button_gradient_color,
                                secondary_button_gradient_color
                              ])),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Sign in",
                            style: button_text_style(),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              colors: [
                                primary_button_gradient_color,
                                secondary_button_gradient_color
                              ])),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset(
                            "Assets/google.svg",
                            height: 20,
                            width: 20,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 15,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Sign in with Google",
                            style: button_text_style(),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 15,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Don't have account? ",
                        style: simple_text_style(),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => SignUp()),
                              (route) => false);
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Register now",
                          style: medium_text_style(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked do you know any blog or site from where I could understand layouts in flutter

Comment: You should checkout the official docs link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout